# Mobile header issue on iphone when scroll up

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, safari, responsive-design

On my website, I have added the fixed position to the header, and its working fine in desktop version and android os phones. but in iPhone when the user scrolls down it works fine but as fast the user starts to scroll up an unknown part of the div appears in the back of the header and it overlaps all the content on the website. I have tried to find that part of div but it's not working. please help.
here is my header code:

```
    #header.header-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9997;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.98);
    height: 70px;
    padding: 15px 0 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #13aafe;
}
```

[image: sample image]

Comment: live version or snippet with tool `<>` please.

Comment: Make `width : 100%;`

Comment: @Simone you can check it live at www[dot]biisummit[dot]com

Comment: @STA just tried but not working

Comment: Actually what the error here?

Comment: @STA if you are using iphone u can see the error when you scroll-up on the website.

Comment: I dont find any error

Comment: @STA, when user scroll up an unknown part of the div, appears in the back of the header and it overlaps all the content on the website you can also see in the image of my question pointing out the black part behind the header.

Comment: i tried [here](http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/?u=http://www.biisummit.com) and all work

Comment: @SimoneRossaini this website doesn't provide actual ios environment. I am using https://live.browserstack.com/dashboard.

Comment: iphone 5 is not ios?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini yes, it is but I am talking about the website you are referring to. that website only providing you the iPhone resolution but not actually iPhone environment

Comment: i will try with real iphone for see final result.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini yeah sure